# Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?

Tags: rust

The following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c1ee7efa123ed8240557c2d086006479&version=stable&backtrace=0))

```
let max_column = 7;
edge = match current_column {
    0 => Edge::Left,
    max_column => Edge::Right,
    _ => Edge::NotAnEdge
};
```

results in the following warning:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
9  |         max_column => Edge::Right,
   |         ---------- matches any value
10 |         _ => Edge::NotAnEdge
   |         ^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
```

Replacing the variable `max_column` with the literal works fine:

```
let max_column = 7;
edge = match current_column {
    0 => Edge::Left,
    7 => Edge::Right,
    _ => Edge::NotAnEdge
};
```

Why is `_` unreachable in the first example when it can be reached for any values where `current_column != max_column`?

Comment: If `max_column` was a constant, it would work, but patterns only work statically.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-02-match.html) explains how a `match` expression is processed, emphasis mine:

> When the `match` expression executes, it compares the resulting value against the pattern of each arm, **in order**.

In your example, `max_column` is the name of the variable to be bound to, **not** a constant or an outside variable. When the compiler reaches `max_column`, any remaining values will be assigned to that match arm, making subsequent arms unreachable.

In your case, you want to make `max_column` a real constant:

```
let current_column = 1;
const MAX_COLUMN: i32 = 7;
edge = match current_column {
    0          => Edge::Left,
    MAX_COLUMN => Edge::Right,
    _          => Edge::NotAnEdge
};
```

Or if that's not possible, you want a *match guard*:

```
let current_column = 1;
let max_column = 7;
edge = match current_column {
    0                    => Edge::Left,
    a if a == max_column => Edge::Right,
    _                    => Edge::NotAnEdge
};
```

Note that, as a first approximation, `a` and `_` are the same thing in this case! In both cases, the matched variable will be bound to a name (`a` or `_` respectively), but any identifier prefixed with `_` is special-cased to be used as an unused variable placeholder.

[bluss clarifies and corrects this approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225958/unreachable-pattern-which-should-be-reachable/28226030?noredirect=1#comment44817813_28226030):

> `_` is a separate special case, it's not a variable binding at all, but it is the absence of one! Matching against `_x` moves the value into `_x`, `_` does no such thing. (The difference is observable.)

Comment: @MikeVella Well, the alternative is that a `x => /* the default case, using x */` match arm stops becoming a default case when a name `x` is introduced in any visible scope. That's inconsistent and, to me, counter-intuitive as well.

Comment: `_` is a separate special case, it's not a variable binding at all, but it is the absence of one! Matching against `_x` moves the value into `_x`, `_` does no such thing. (The difference is observable.)

Comment: Would be nice if there was a way to "pin" a variable [as in Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator). In this case, `^ MAX_COLUMN =>` would mean, "match against this variable" instead of "assign value to this variable name".

Comment: @richardpringle that doesn't make sense with the semantics of `match`. Match patterns must be verified at **compile time**, so having a variable cannot work as it would need to be checked at runtime. That's why a `const` works — it's known at compile time. `static` and `let` variables can change during program execution. The match guard syntax calls out that the check is moving from compile time to runtime.

Comment: I'm saying that a little syntactic sugar would be nice. `^x => {}` would desugar to `y if y == x => {}`. This new syntax would also call out that the check is moving from compile-time to runtime. It would cut down on boilerplate at the cost of adding another operator. Not sure if you could accomplish the same thing with a macro...