# Why does a match expression with an unknown identifier compile and run?

Tags: rust

I would expect the Rust compiler to complain about the missing cases in match as well as the unknown identifier:

```
pub enum MyEnum {
    Case1,
    Case2,
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn my_func(&self) {
        match self {
            _whatever_string => println!("Why am I printed ?"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyEnum::Case1;
    x.my_func();
}
```

Why does it compile and call the `println`?

Comment: Heavily related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28225958/1233251

Answer (score 4):

Your example is a special case of something explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/book/match.html):

```
let x = 5;

let number = match x {
    1 => "one",
    2 => "two",
    3 => "three",
    4 => "four",
    5 => "five",
    _ => "something else",
};
```

Consider the last case (`_`), which matches anything not mentioned before. The compiler does not complain about missing cases (since "everything else" is covered by the last branch).

Your example is essentially the same: A `match` with one single arm that covers everything. You could also have written `_` instead of `_whatever_string`, or another identifier - that could then be used in the corresponding arm.

So, this `match` just matches and executes the statements in its single arm. The compiler sees that the single branch covers everything and does not need to complain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought only '_' was accepted as the default arm but it seems not. I can even add more "whatever_identifier" cases without the compiler to complain (except warnings).

Comment: Any implicitly typed, unconstrained identifier can match any value.