# Is it possible to pattern match with a custom equality operator?

Tags: rust

I'm just learning Rust, and I was wondering if there is a possibility of taking this code:

```
match letter.to_lowercase().as_str() {
    "a" => 5,
    "n" => 13,
    // And so on...
    _   => 0,
}
```

and using `String::eq_ignore_ascii_case` as the equality operator instead, like in the pseudocode below:

```
match letter with letter.eq_ignore_ascii_case as operator {
    "a" => 5,
    "n" => 13,
    // And so on...
    _   => 0,
}
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225958/why-is-this-match-pattern-unreachable-when-using-non-literal-patterns

Comment: `match` doesn't use any equality operator for any type, it uses structural equality. You can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, **no**, unless you write your own type wrapper that actually **normalize** your input into something you need.

What you can do is to match `to_ascii_lowercase`:

```rust
match letter.to_ascii_lowercase().as_str() {
        "a" => 5,
        "n" => 13,
        // And so on...
        _   => 0,
    }
```

From the [`eq_ignore_ascii_case`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.eq_ignore_ascii_case):

> Checks that two strings are an ASCII case-insensitive match.
> Same as to_ascii_lowercase(a) == to_ascii_lowercase(b), but without
> allocating and copying temporaries.

Comment: I fail to see how "write your own type wrapper" would help, unless the type wrapper would essentially require a `new` function that calls `to_lowercase`. And the OP contains the example with `to_lowercase`, so I fail to see how your `to_ascii_lowercase` is useful.

Comment: @mcarton, would you mind expand why would `to_ascii_lowercase` do not work?
You are right about the wrapper type though. He would have to transform the underliying item anyway.

Comment: `to_ascii_lowercase` would work, but it's barely an improvement when the OP mentions `to_lowercase` already.